# iOS - How to access variable from a class to be used in AppleDelegate.m

Tags: ios, objective-c, class

I have a class named AddAlarmViewController and declared two variables.

Declare Variable

```
@interface AddAlarmViewController ()
{
    NSString *soundName;
    NSString *soundName2;
}
```

I have this method to get the name of the alarm tone from picker view

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
      inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    soundName = _alarmNames[row];
    soundName2 = [soundName stringByAppendingString:@".caf"];
}
```

Now, I want to use soundName2 in another class which is AppleDelegate.m. This is the line of code in AppleDelegate.m that I want to do.

```
notification.soundName = soundName2;
```

How do I do this?

Comment: This looks like the sort of information that you should store in `NSUserDefaults` - you can then read the value in your app delegate and the value will persist between executions of your app

Comment: I would register AppDelegate for a notification and would trigger that notification from your `didSelectRow` method

Answer (score 1):

On your AddAlarmViewController

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
      inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    soundName = _alarmNames[row];
    soundName2 = [soundName stringByAppendingString:@".caf"];

    NSDictionary *payload = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:soundName2 forKey:@"NewSound"]];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"NewSoundSelected" object:self withUserInfo:payload];

}
```

Somewhere on your AppDelegate, probably inside of didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(doSomethingWithNewSound:) name:@"NewSoundSelected" object:nil];
```

Then add the following method to your AppDelegate

```
-(void) doSomethingWithNewSound:(NSNotification *) notification {
   NSDictionary *payload = [notification userInfo];

   //Here is what you are looking for
   NSString *sound = [payload objectForKey:@"NewSound"];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface AddAlarmViewController ()
{
    NSString *soundName;
    NSString *soundName2;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *soundName;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *soundName2;
```

Now `import AddAlarmViewController.h` in your `Appdelegate.m` file
Then Create Object of `AddAlarmViewController` Through That Object you Can Access Those two Strings.

```
AddAlarmViewController *restInfoView=[[AddAlarmViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddAlarmViewController" bundle:nil];
notification.soundName = restInfoView.soundName2;
```